# What's the best way to store a JSON file with complex data structure for later use?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, plist

So I have an iOS app and this JSON file (about 50 MB) that has a deep tree structure. The goal is to store this file locally and use its content later on the app, with the possibility of updating the data or some parts of it in the future..

After some research, I found out that I can use core data, but it seems inconvenient for such complex structure.

So, I thought maybe I'll persist the data in a class object, but this may end up consuming the whole mobile memory.

Now, I'm thinking if it is plausible to store the data in a plist then map the hell out of it to present its content.

What do you think guys? Do you have any other ideas or thoughts?

Comment: Why not use the SAX json parser available and keep the json itself in app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and reflexion, I ended up using Realm for its simplicity and effectiveness.

Answer (score 3):

Just store the JSON as you received it, as NSData. It doesn't care one bit about the structure, so you can parse it again.

Comment: I agree with this solution. You can also just save the json as text file and load up and parse again. I also do this in my app.